# Firebase - RealTime Database - Rules and Auth

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, flutter-web

1. I'm designing a web application to be able to conduct online questionnaires.
2. I've deployed the Flutter web app to Firebase hosting and the app's database lies in the Firebase real-time DB.
3. Since anyone can submit a response, I really don't want to set up an OAuth-based authentication system.
4. However, I also do NOT want my APIs to be open to everyone as this poses a security risk.

This is how my request headers look (as of now) -

```
Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
       'Content-type': 'application/json',
       'Accept': 'application/json',
     };
```

This is how the realtime db rules look like -

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    
  }
}
```

Now, the question is, how can I make sure that my APIs are not exposed to everyone while I still can use them inside my application (which works without any user auth)?

Also, I want to make sure that Firebase DB at least checks that a request is coming from within my deployed web app and only then it lets it use the APIs. If someone is going to those APIs directly (from outside the app, in the browser, they simply should not work).

Is there any way I can achieve this ?? Probably by sending something inside those headers and then checking the same on the server before the data is sent back to the client.

Your help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: If you do not want to keep track of users then anonymous login might help you. You just have to configure it such that there's minimum effort required from users end, and then you can change your security rules to allow read and writes if user is authenticated. And for checking if the request is valid, you can use the `App check` feature which is still in beta but works fine!

Comment: Hey there! I'm kind of new to firebase. Can you suggest a good article on how i can achieve this ? and let's say I send some hard coded auth token inside by request headers. Is there a way for me to validate it in the RealTime db rules ? That would at least make sure that the get/post request is coming from within the application as that would be the only way for request header to contain that token. Is it possible ?

Comment: To get started with anonymous auth: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth. To get started with app check: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check